# Java LinkedList adding multiple nodes

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, implementation

my question is in my main method, how to add multiple nodes to the linked list....What I have now with first, node2, node3..I thought was adding those nodes but I realized I don't think I'm actually doing anything with those nodes and their values, right?  How do I use setData() and setNext() to add all of those nodes.  Does that make sense?

```
ListNode<String> node4 = new ListNode<String>("Fourth", null);
ListNode<String> node3 = new ListNode<String>("Third", node4);
ListNode<String> node2 = new ListNode<String>("Second", node3);
ListNode<String> first = new ListNode<String>("First", node2);
```

If the above sets up the values how do I add them all?

Do I then need to set the data and next for each one of these?  (This seems redundant since I seem to be setting up the value of each nodes data and next in the constructor above?)

```
first.setData("first");
first.setNext(node2); 
node2.setData("Second");
node2.setNext(node2);
//.....
```

I'm trying to add all of the above nodes so I can test my addLast() method by adding a new node.  However, when I call my addLast() method in main as you can see below the only thing that's printed is that addLast() value I added (and first if I call addFirst()).

Test Class

```
public class LinkedListDriver
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();                   //comment out this line to test your code
        SinglyLinkedList<String> list = new SinglyLinkedList<String>(); //remove comment to test your code

        ListNode<String> node4 = new ListNode<String>("Fourth", null);
        ListNode<String> node3 = new ListNode<String>("Third", node4);
        ListNode<String> node2 = new ListNode<String>("Second", node3);
        ListNode<String> first = new ListNode<String>("First", node2);

        ListNode value = new ListNode("First", new ListNode("Second", new ListNode("Third", null)));

        //I've been messing around with this but 
        list.addFirst(first.getData());
        list.addFirst("Second");

        list.addLast("Fifth");
        list.printList();
    }
}
```

I didn't add my other two classes because I didn't think it was relevant but if you'd like to see it let me know.  I'm very new this is only my second class and it's online and is poorly constructed class, please be nice lol

SinglyLinkedList class

```
//This class implements a very simple singly-linked list of Objects
public class SinglyLinkedList<E>
{
    ListNode<E> first; // first element

    public SinglyLinkedList() {
        first = null;
    }

    public E getFirst() {
        if (first == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        } else
            return first.getData();
    }

    public void addFirst(E value) {
        first = new ListNode<E>(value, first);
    }

    // Methods below implemented by you. Note: while writing methods, keep in mind
    // that you might be able to call other methods in this class to help you - you
    // don't always need to start from scratch(but you'll have to recognize when)

    public void addLast(E value) {
        ListNode<E> temp = first;
        //If list is empty make new node the first node.
        if (temp == null) {
            first = new ListNode <E>(value, null);
            first.setNext(null);
        }//Otherwise loop to end of list and add new node.
        else {
            while (temp.getNext() != null) {
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            temp.setNext(new ListNode<E>(value, null));
        }
    }//end addLast

    // throws an exception - you decide when and which one

    public E getLast() {
        ListNode<E> temp = first;
        if (temp == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("There are no elements in this list to get.");
        } else {
            while (temp.getNext() != null) {
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            return temp.getData();
        }
    }

    // throws an exception - you decide when and which one

    public E removeFirst() {
        if (first == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("There are no elements in this list to remove.");
        }
        ListNode<E> tempRemove = first;
        return null; //just so it'll compile
    }

    // throws an exception - you decide when and which one

    public E removeLast() {
        return null; //just so it'll compile
    }

    // return the number of elements in the list

    public int size() {
        return 0; //just so it'll compile
    }

    // return true if o is in this list, otherwise false

    public boolean contains(E obj) {
        return true; //just so it'll compile
    }

    public void printList(java.io.PrintStream out) {
        if (first == null) {
            System.out.println("The list is empty");
        }
        ListNode<E> current = first;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.toString());
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "[";
        ListNode<E> current = first;
        //write code to traverse the list, adding each object on its own line
        while (current.getNext() != null) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        s += "]";
        return s;
    }

    // OPTIONAL: just for fun...and a challenge

    public void reverse() {
    }
}
```

ListNode class is your basic getNext setNext, getData setData....

Comment: Ok, so I should be using the SinglyLinkedList object I set up at the beginning of main to add those nodes?

Comment: I'm still a little confused, I'm going to post my SinglyLinkedList class for you to see if you could let me know what methods I should be using to add these nodes?  The only thing I could think is the addFirst() method but how do I add the nodes that follow the first?  Does that make sense?

Comment: I get that and that makes sense but the most confusing part for me with LinkedLists right now is how to add multiple nodes.  The videos I have watched showed examples like I have and I see how that sets up the structure of the values and what the next nodes will be but I'm not actually adding those values and I don't know how to.  I would like to have those nodes added so I can test all the other methods I write more easily.

Comment: I have moved my comments into an answer to clean up a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points, mostly summarizing the comments:

You shouldn't work with `ListNode` objects in `main()` at all - that should be the job of the `SinglyLinkedList` class. `ListNode` doesn't even need to be visible to the rest of the code, it could be a nested class in `SinglyLinkedList`. You should only be exchanging the data objects (Strings in this case) with `SinglyLinkedList`.

If you want to test for example the `addLast()` method, you could start with an empty list and repeatedly call `list.addLast()`, as Shane mentions in his answer. That way you will make sure it works when the list is empty as well as nonempty.

```
SinglyLinkedList<String> list = new SinglyLinkedList<String>();
list.addLast("first");
list.addLast("second");
list.addLast("third");
list.printList(System.out);
```

As for adding multiple nodes in a single call - this linked list doesn't have a method for that. You could add a method for adding all elements of an array for example, but you can just call `addLast()` sequentially with the same effect. You can create some helper method in the main class to populate the list in this way, if you want to start with some base data for testing other methods.

As a side note: if `printList()` takes `java.io.PrintStream out` as argument, you should use it instead of `System.out`. That is

```
out.println(...)
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(...)
```

Also, it's better to throw `NoSuchElementException` rather than `NullPointerException` as an indication that the requested element doesn't exist.

If you want a convenient way to populate the list, you could have something like this in your main class:

```
static <E> void addToList(SinglyLinkedList<E> list, E... values) {
    for (E value : values) {
        list.addLast(value);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
SinglyLinkedList<String> list = new SinglyLinkedList<String>();
addToList(list, "first", "second", "third");
```

Comment: Oh ok, that's basically what I wanted to know was how to add multiple nodes.  Essentially I need a plain add method or I can use addFirst or addLast multiple times to populate the LinkedList?   So the videos I was watching made it seem like you added nodes how I had it above, when would that approach be useful?  Or combining it all on one line like....ListNode value = new ListNode("First", new ListNode("Second"....

Comment: Because that's my objective was to start with some base data to test the new methods created.

Comment: @sjud9227 You can use `addFirst()` or `addLast()` to populate the list, the difference will be the order of the values in the list. Then there could be `add(int index)` to add to a specific position, but you're not required to implement that one. The video you saw was probably about working with linked nodes in general, where each node could be used separately. But here you have a list with its own defined methods, so you only need to work with nodes in that class and nowhere else.

Comment: @sjud9227 See my edit (at the end) for an example of a method for populating the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cinnam!  You helped me out a lot and I appreciate you explaining things, I want to learn not just get the answers.  So again thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? If you're attempting to populate the linked list, all you need to do is continually call list.addLast, which will take a single parameter (the data in the new node you're adding), and deal with creating the new node and placing it in the back of the list.

You shouldn't need to create any nodes in your main, I'm assuming, as they are generally handled entirely by the linkedlist class.

Comment: No I want to add those nodes so that I can test addLast() and make sure it's working correctly, but not just addLast, I have other methods I'm trying to implement and I would like to use the list with those nodes in it to test those other methods too

Comment: FYI, that was not me who down voted your answer Shane.